# The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications / ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: asp.net-core

I have deployed a .NET Core 3.1 application via IIS on my local machine. My launchsettings.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:56205",
      "sslPort": 44376
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "nativeDebugging": false
    },
    "NewProject - Production": {
      "commandName": "NewProject",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }    
  }
}
```

I have a file called appsettings.Production.json that looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
    
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Home_ConString": "[...connString info...]"
  }
}
```

I can browse the main index of the site no problem, but the moment that I click a link to go to a different view, I see this error:

[image: Error message]

I don't understand why I am still seeing this error. I have hard-coded my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variables to equal "Production", so there is no longer any mention of a development environment in my code. Any idea as to why I am still running in to this issue?

Comment: The page you are seeing there only tells you that an error happened. And because you are using "Production" as your environment the detailed error is hidden. ASP.NET here tells you to turn on "Development Mode" if you want the detailed error to be displayed in the browser - which you should **not** do when you run the application in production.
Please try to debug your application to figure out what the actual error is

Comment: Xerillio - wow, the resolution was right in the error message. Thank you for pointing that out - I don't know why I didn't think to rename the profile to "Development". I've coded in Visual Studio for years, but I've not worked much with IIS and I didn't think that after deploying to IIS, I'm still "developing". Thank you so much! =)